# What happens when you break the for statement with a range channel

Tags: for-loop, go

I'm following this code to get a lazy range of numbers with **channels**

```golang
// iterator
func iterator(n int, c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
    close(c)
    fmt.Println("iterator End")
}

c := make(chan int)
go iterator(5, c)
for i := range c {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

This will print as expected

```
0
1
2
3
4
fmt.Println("iterator End")
```

But what happened when I break the **for** loop like this

```golang
c := make(chan int)
go getNumbers(5, c)
for i := range c {
    if i == 2 {
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

It seems the goroutine is blocked because never prints `iterator End` (I also try by sleeping the main thread).
I'm wondering how to handle this scenario?
Did I need to use `select` to resolve this?
There is any safe way to check if the range was **break** and stop the **for-loop** in the iterator?

Comment: `make(chan int)` creates a channel with length of 0. This is also called an unbuffered channel, and means that any write to it will block until a matching read happens. Since you stop reading while the go routine blocks on a write, it will block on that write forever. A bad way to fix this would be to create a channel with enough size to store the remaining 2 values, using `make(chan int, 2)`. (Note that in your code, you still read an `int` of `2` from the channel, but `break` before printing it) The good solution uses `context.Context` as outlined by the answer below.

Comment: "I'm wondering how to handle this scenario?" Don't  do this. "Did I need to use select to resolve this?" ??? "There is any safe way to check if the range was break and stop the for-loop in the iterator?" No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a goroutine writes to an unbuffered channel and no other goroutine is reading from the channel - then the writes will block forever. This will cause a goroutine leak. This is what you are experiencing.

If you have a "producer" goroutine which writes to a channel, you need a way to signal it to stop. Closing the channel is not the critical part here - as channels are garbage collected when they go out of scope. A blocked goroutine (that will never unblock) is considered a leak as it will never be reclaimed, so you really need the goroutine to end.

You can signal an intent to quit in many ways - the two most popular being:

- a `done` channel; or
- [context.Context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) cancelation

### Signal: done channel

```
func iterator(n int, c chan int, done <-chan struct{}) {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        select {
        case c <- i:
        case <-done:
            break
        }
    }
    close(c)
    fmt.Println("iterator End")
}
```

reader goroutine:

```
c := make(chan int)
done := make(chan struct{})
go iterator(5, c, done)
for i := range c {
    if i == 2 {
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(i)
}
close(done) // signal writer goroutine to quit
```

### Signal: context.Context

```
func iterator(ctx context.Context, n int, c chan int) {
        defer close(c)
        defer fmt.Println("iterator End")

        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                select {
                case c <- i:
                case <-ctx.Done():
                        fmt.Println("canceled. Reason:", ctx.Err())
                        return
                }
        }
}
```

read goroutine:

```
func run(ctx context.Context) {
        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
        defer cancel()  // call this regardless - avoid context leaks - but signals producer your intent to stop
        c := make(chan int)
        go iterator(ctx, 5, c)
        for i := range c {
                if i == 2 {
                        break
                }
                fmt.Println(i)
        }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4-fDyCurB7t

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the documentation at https://golang.org/pkg/context/ is being needlessly technical and abstract about what `Context` is. It talks about "request scope", "API boundaries" and "servers". To put it simply, `Context` is the most glorified boolean in all of Go, and allows you to tell a go routine that it should terminate using various language semantics; the go routine which runs `main()` is not exempt from this.

Comment: Agreed. Which is why I led with a simple `done` channel. When writing a microservice using gRPC, REST etc. - `context.Context` is already baked-in for free - so its worth getting used to how they work.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I didn't have in mind about `context.Context`. Is good to know it.